# python extend pandas.DataFrame.groupby().groups value list of type int64index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame `df` on which i use: `df.groupby('something').groups` to get a dict with layout { group : list of indices per group }.

```
maxProteinPeptidesDict = defaultdict(list, df.loc[peptideIndices].groupby("Master Protein Accessions").groups)
(...)
for multipleProteinsString, nonUniqueIndices in multipleProteinPeptidesDict.items():
    multipleProteins = multipleProteinsString.split('; ')
    for protein in multipleProteins: # extend the possibly (probably) already existing entry in the dict.
        maxProteinPeptidesDict[protein].extend(nonUniqueIndices)
```

However, the lists in the dict values (`maxProteinPeptidesDict[protein]`) are of type Int64Index. I then want to extend them, but Int64Index has no extend method.
How can i circumvent this? Is casting every single Int64Index to a list the only option?

BTW1: I'm using a defaultdict because for technical reasons I cannot know whether the entry `maxProteinPeptidesDict[protein]` already exists or not before I start adding (more) values to it.
BTW2: a groupby object also has an an attribute 'indices' but this seems to return something different than the actual indices in the dataframe...

Comment: Could you please 1. add some code example; 2. provide a little bit broader context: what is your actual problem, why do you really have to extend those indexes?

Comment: I agree with Ilya on all points. There's a good chance you don't need to extend them in order to achieve your goal. `g = df.groupby('something')` and then `g.get_group(gp)`for example. Worst case you can use the Int64Index directly e.g. `df.iloc[df.groupby('something').groups[gp]]` or the indices `df.loc[df.groupby('something').indices[gp]]`

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov , I added some more code and info. Is this enough information for you?